# Spring Cloud Contract. Сгенерированный тест падает с эксепшеном: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You haven't configured a MockMVC instance

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Пишу контрактный тест на REST контроллер с использованием mockMvc. Когда делаю clean package/install то в консоли показывается, что сгенерированный контрактный тест падает с эксепшеном:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You haven't configured a MockMVC instance. You can do this statically

RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(..)
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(..);
RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(..);

or using the DSL:

given().
        mockMvc(..). ..

    at io.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcFactory.build(MockMvcFactory.java:52)
    at io.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.when(MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.java:571)
    at io.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.get(MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.java:582)
    at io.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.get(MockMvcRequestSpecificationImpl.java:65)
    at com.flamelab.users.controller.AdmincontrollerTest.validate_giving_admin_user_details_by_id(AdmincontrollerTest.java:29)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста решение, кто сталкивался с проблемой.

Код базового тестового класса

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AdminController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AdminControllerTestConfig.class, TestConfig.class, AdminControllerTestProperty.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AdminController.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/AdminControllerTest.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AdminControllerContractBaseTest {
    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ObjectId id = new ObjectId("5a26af97857aba000719ea2e");
        Admin admin = createAdminUser();
        when(adminRepository.findOneByCredentialsId(id)).thenReturn(admin);
    }
}
```

Код контракта

```
Contract.make {
name("Giving admin user details by id")
request {
    method(HttpMethods.HttpMethod.GET)
    urlPath("/api/admin/5a26af97857aba000719ea2e")
    }

    response {
        status 200
    }
}
```

Код сгенерированного теста:

```
public class AdmincontrollerTest extends AdminControllerContractBaseTest {

@Test
public void validate_giving_admin_user_details_by_id() throws Exception {
    // given:
        MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given();

    // when:
        ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                .get("/api/admin/5a26af97857aba000719ea2e");

    // then:
        assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ещё момент: в методе setup() если дописать с самого начала метода RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new AdminController()); то выдаётся та же ошибка.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать аннотацию "@AutoConfigureMockMvc" и сделать "RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(this.mockMvc)"

Comment: aleshka-batman, благодарю за отзыв, но увы не сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге, потанцевав с бубном нашел решение. 
(в комментарии я указывал, что добавляю RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new AdminController()); - тоесть тестирую AdminController, который имеет аннотацию @RESTController).

Суть решения в том, что в тестируемый AdminController я добавил конструктор. Изначально поля в этот класс автовайрились через @Autowired, но без конструктора. Я создал конструктор с параметрами полей этого класса, после чего убрал с полей аннотации @Autowired. Далее, в базовом классе для тестов, в методе setup на котором стоит аннотация @Before, я написал следующее:

```
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @Autowired
    private CredentialsService credentialsService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Admin admin = createAdminUser();
        when(adminRepository.findOneByCredentialsId(id)).thenReturn(admin);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new AdminController(adminService, credentialsService));
    }
```

new AdminController(adminService, credentialsService) - эта часть фактически стала решением.

Ошибка java.lang.IllegalStateException: You haven't configured a MockMVC instance возникала по той причине, что MckMvc хоть и было заавтовайрино в базовом тестовом классе, однако во время прохождения самого теста mockMvc инстанс был = null. А в таком варианте, когда я передаю в тестируемый контроллер параметры, mockMvc создаётся.

Надеюсь моё решение поможет кому-то ещё.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,classes = SpringCloudContractProducerApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
public class BaseTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private EvenOddController evenOddController;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(evenOddController);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder);
    }
}
```

Причина :

> Your base classes are using JUnit 4 imports - https://github.com/LoganDev99/springcdc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/cdc/BaseClass.java#L3 and the generated test is using JUnit 5 ones. Please change @Before to @BeforeEach and remove the @RunWith annotation.

[Здесь](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1601)